Avro: Decode using multiprocessing in Python
In terms of best performance with less latency, which asynchronous approach would be better towards decoding the Avro message that is consumed from the Kafka topic?
I was using concurrent futures with the Avro library, and I can still see the similar execution time as compared to the one without using concurrent futures.
from avro.io import BinaryDecoder, DatumReader
from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient

class DoIt():
    def some_method():
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
                msg_cnt_type_futures = [executor.submit(DoIt.decode_avro, avro, self.schema_url) for avro in avro_list]


    @staticmethod
    def decode_avro(payload_tuple, schema_url):
        msg_id, current_msg_offset, payload = payload_tuple
        magic, schema_id = struct.unpack('>bi', payload[:5])
        register_client = CachedSchemaRegistryClient(url=schema_url)
        schema = register_client.get_by_id(schema_id)
        reader = DatumReader(schema)
        output = BinaryDecoder(io.BytesIO(payload[5:]))
        decoded = reader.read(output)
        return msg_id, current_msg_offset, decoded, schema.name



A minor note: Assuming the payload you're getting in decode_avro is a bytes or bytearray object, and said object is frequently large, you might benefit from wrapping it in a memoryview so the large slice isn't copying all that data. Just change output = BinaryDecoder(io.BytesIO(payload[5:])) to output = BinaryDecoder(io.BytesIO(memoryview(payload)[5:])) so you slice a view of the data. Alternatively, make the IO object, bio = io.BytesIO(payload), skip what you don't care about, bio.seek(5), then use it, output = BinaryDecoder(bio).

On the other hand, if the objects are typically small but numerous, you could save time on decoding the avro header by precompiling a struct.Struct. Define AVRO_HEADER = struct.Struct(">bi") at top level, outside the method, and in the function, replace magic, schema_id = struct.unpack('>bi', payload[:5]) with magic, schema_id = AVRO_HEADER.unpack_from(payload) (by using unpack_from, you don't need to slice payload, saving a little more work on top of being able to bypass the Python level code of struct.unpack in favor of precompiled C code of struct.Struct methods).

Multiprocessing is an inherently insane solution to deserializing from avro storage, and deserializing in general (unless the serialization format is pathologically slow to deserialize). Avro is a serialization format which you are deserializing. Dispatching a task to a worker and receiving a result means:

Pickling the task data (serialization, not in parallel, though it's likely relatively cheap since the serialized avro data is probably just a byte stream that can be sent mostly unchanged)
Sending it to the worker via IPC (I/O, though cheaper than disk I/O)
The worker unpickles the task data (deserialization, though done in parallel so at least it goes fast)
The worker deserializes the avro (deserialization in parallel)
The worker pickles the result (serialization in parallel)
The worker sends it back to the parent via IPC (I/O)
The parent unpickles it (deserialization, not in parallel, and more expensive because it's reproducing the same objects that were originally encoded in avro)

You've taken a deserialization process, and turned it into two rounds of serialization and three rounds of deserialization, and one of each round is done serially (not in parallel). The only reason you're not running slower with multiprocessing is that avro is a slightly slower format to work with than pickles, and that part is being parallelized, with the serial work being the slightly faster/cheaper pickle work. But this will never work.
If your avro decoder is a C extension that releases the GIL during decoding, then you could potentially see a small gain from changing from multiprocessing to multithreading; just change concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor to concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor, and try it out to see if it helps. If that doesn't help, your options are pretty limited. You could switch to a GIL-free Python interpreter (there aren't many, and they're usually years behind on features relative to the CPython reference interpreter and the most common alternative interpreter, PyPy, both of which use a GIL). You could write your own C extension to do the work (or find an existing C extension to do it). But fundamentally, the cost of talking to another process, and the inherent serialization and deserialization process involved in doing so, means that the possible speed ups are limited to parallelizing within a single process.
In short: Your best performance, without switching languages, is probably just the single-threaded serial deserialization you started with, though with a good C extension you might benefit from multi-threading (it would be hard to do, because creating the Python objects from the deserialization must be done with the GIL held, reducing possible parallelism; at best it could decode from avro to C data types in parallel, then reacquire the GIL and convert from C to Python types).
